# If I create smart contracts for my clients on fiverr, upwork, etc., can I be arrested in Bangladesh?

Tags: cryptocurrency, freelance, bangladesh, non-fungible-token

The legality of cryptocurrency is a bit tricky in Bangladesh. A cautionary notice issued by the Bangladesh bank on December 24, 2017, said:

[image]

My translation:

> Recently, it has been known from various news media outlets and the
> internet that online-based virtual currencies or cryptocurrencies
> namely Bitcoin, Ethereum, Ripple, Litecoin, etc. are being transacted
> on various exchange platforms. These virtual currencies are not legal
> currencies (legal tender) issued by the legal authority of any
> country, and therefore there will be no financial claim recognized
> against these virtual currencies. Transactions done using these
> currencies are not approved by the Bangladesh Bank or any other
> regulatory organization, and therefore the use of these virtual
> currencies is not supported by [The Foreign Exchange Regulation Act,
> 1947](http://bdlaws.minlaw.gov.bd/act-218.html?lang=en); [The Anti Terrorism Act, 2009](https://www.satp.org/satporgtp/countries/bangladesh/document/papers/AntiTerrorism_Act2009.pdf), and [The Money Laundering
> Prevention Act, 2012](https://www.satp.org/Docs/Document/61.pdf). The laws related to money laundering and the
> prevention of the financing of terrorism may be violated
> unintentionally when transactions with a nameless/pseudonymous partner
> are done using virtual currencies. Mainly: payment and settlement of
> monetary value take place through an online-based network, and as it
> is not recognized by any central authority/payment system/regulatory
> authority,   customers (users) can face various risks including
> financial and legal risks.
>
> Under the circumstances, to avoid the probable financial and legal
> risks, the general people are being requested to refrain from
> performing, assisting, and advertising transactions through virtual
> currencies such as Bitcoin.

Also, to understand the background information better, [I'll append some commentary provided by Barristers-at-Law and Associates, Mahbub & Company below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikATY.jpg):

> However, from the two cautionary notices published by the central
> bank, it is evident that the regulator has fallen short of “banning”
> or “criminalising” the use of bitcoin except in cases where it is used
> to commit an existing offence under the Foreign Exchange Regulation
> Act, the Anti-Money Laundering Act and the Anti-Terrorism Act. It
> could be argued that the use of regular currency to commit crimes
> under the same Acts would be similarly punishable, and as such while
> bitcoin itself is not illegal, its use to commit crime is.
>
> Bangladesh Bank's declaration that it is not legal tender finds
> resonance with the regulatory response in most countries. However, it
> could be argued that bitcoin not being accepted or recognised as legal
> tender does not necessarily make it illegal. The legal basis of a
> “warning” published by the Bangladesh Bank is also questionable.
>
> The Foreign Exchange Regulation Act and Money Laundering Prevention
> Act contain provisions for punishment and criminal liability, for
> trading, importing, and exporting currencies without authorisation of
> the Bangladesh or if not performed through an authorised dealer, and
> for illegally laundering proceeds of crime or foreign currency. The
> definition of currency is given in section 2(b) of the Foreign
> Exchange Regulation Act, which includes:
>
> (i) all coins, currency notes, bank notes, postal notes, money orders,
> cheques, drafts, traveler's cheques, letters of credit, bills of
> exchange and promissory notes; and
>
> (ii) such other similar physical or non-physical instruments, or both
> as may be notified by the Bangladesh Bank from time to time;”
>
> Despite its name, bitcoin is not a coin, and also does not match any
> of the items listed in section 2(b)(i). As for section 2(b)(ii), there
> is a positive obligation upon Bangladesh Bank to make a statutory
> notification and declare that cryptocurrency or bitcoin is “currency”
> for it to be classified as such, but it has not done that till date.
> Thus, it appears that bitcoin or other virtual cryptocurrencies may
> not fall within the purview of the definition of “currency” under
> section 2(b) of the Foreign Exchange Regulation Act. That being the
> case, criminal offences relating to trading foreign currency without
> authorisation, arguably do not explicitly catch bitcoin or
> cryptocurrencies.
>
> According to section 2(s) of the Money Laundering Prevention Act,
> foreign currency means any foreign exchange defined under section 2(d)
> of the Foreign Exchange Regulation Act. However, similarly, the
> definition of foreign currency in Money Laundering Prevention Act is
> referred to foreign “currency”, which, as discussed earlier,
> apparently does not cover bitcoin and cryptocurrencies.
>
> It is not clear, upon what basis, the “warnings” regarding legality of
> bitcoin have been issued so far. The warnings also refer to the
> Anti-Terrorism Act which criminalises funding of terrorism, but the
> Act does not make any reference to bitcoin, cryptocurrency or any
> other currency whatsoever.
>
> Despite Bangladesh Bank's warnings discussed above, the Acts of
> Parliament which they apparently are based upon, fall short of
> criminalising or even banning bitcoin or crytocurrency. However, the
> fact remains that Bangladeshi authorities are adamant to stop the use
> of bitcoin and are reportedly hunting bitcoin traders and miners.
>
> In the wake of the global trend in the use of cryptocurrency, it is
> high time that Bangladesh comes up with a properly formulated
> regulatory response to bitcoin instead of going after users on an ad
> hoc basis. It is also vital for the central bank and lawmakers to join
> the global discussion on regulating cryptocurrency immediately and
> participate in concerted efforts to ensure that the use of this new
> technology is only for the good of the society and economy.

Miscellaneous: [National Blockchain Strategy: Bangladesh](https://bcc.portal.gov.bd/sites/default/files/files/bcc.portal.gov.bd/page/bdb0a706_e674_4a40_a8a8_7cfccf7e9d9b/2020-10-19-15-03-391a6d9d1eb062836b440256cee34935.pdf)

**My question:**

1. Will it be illegal for me to code smart contracts for my potential clients in fiverr/upwork etc.? As far as I know, coding NFT smart contracts and minting websites don't require the transaction of cryptocurrencies. However, will I not be "assisting" cryptocurrency transactions? Bangladesh bank asked me to refrain from that when it said

> Under the circumstances, to avoid the probable financial and legal
> risks, the general people are being requested to refrain from
> performing, **assisting**, and advertising transactions through virtual
> currencies such as Bitcoin.

[Example gig](https://www.fiverr.com/barakacap/create-a-responsive-website-with-react-js?context_referrer=search_gigs&source=main_banner&ref_ctx_id=d22c654226e625928add7ed7e9d4e8dc&pckg_id=1&pos=7&context_type=auto&funnel=d22c654226e625928add7ed7e9d4e8dc&imp_id=7486c660-564f-475b-8e0d-18bfe4780c0a): I'd like to do gigs like this. Will this be illegal in Bangladesh?